# Duplicate column style

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to **duplicate entire column style**, instead of cell range, because it is slow and limited. I have a XLSX model file and it set default style that my final file will be like, but some columns are dynamic, so I "duplicate this column" and re-apply styles again.

**My current work model:**

[image: my current work model]

**What I spect on *duplicate* column:**

[image: what I spect on *duplicate* column]

**What I get current on my method:**

[image: what I get current on my method]

**My current method**

My current method is `insertNewColumnBeforeByIndex()` to create a new empty dynamic column, so I `duplicateStyle("D2")` to new one, and `duplicateStyle("D3")` to `D3:Dx` (where `x` is the latest row filled, like `getHighestRow()`).

**What I search for**

1. A method to duplicate all column (or copy and paste after model column); or,
2. A method to clone style of column X to Y;

**What I tried too**

- Google it;
- Tried to `duplicateStyle()` from model to `X1048576`, and after some minutes I get `memory exhaustion` fail;

On **PHPExcel 1.8.0**.